# Python - Conditional regex matching

Tags: python, regex

Python does unexpectingly not match strings I would like to be matched:

The following function scans a directory for subdirectories, that have a specific name format.
If matched, it shall print it out. The regex is correct, I checked it: [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR3vQ4/2).

Still, the conditional block doesn't print out anything, while the print-command before shows, that the directories I am looking for exist. So it should match, but doesn't;

```
def getRelevantFolders():
    pattern = re.compile('(e|d|b)-(heme|gome|jome)-(?!.*?\/)(.+)')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/jome'):
        print root # f.e.: /jome/stat/d-heme-sdfsdf
        if pattern.match(root):
            print ('Matched: ' + root)
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `search` instead of `match`, because `match` matches always from the beginning of the string.

```
def getRelevantFolders():
    pattern = re.compile('[edb]-(heme|gome|jome)-([^/]+)')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/jome'):
        print root # f.e.: /jome/stat/d-heme-sdfsdf
        if pattern.search(root):
            print 'Matched: ' + root
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) because `re.match` match the pattern from leading :

```
pattern.search(root)
```

In python wiki :

If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use `search()` instead (see also [search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)).

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: [re.match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).